# Wamp - localhost opens project url in www directory

Tags: localhost, virtualhost

I did setting to create virtual host which were executed successfully. I referred [this guide](http://laternastudio.com/blog/setting-up-an-apache-2-2-21-virtual-host-windows). I made changes in three files:

- httpd.conf
- host file in - C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
- httpd-vhosts.conf - D:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra

I reverted all the changes and now when I open localhost it opens 'abc' project in my www directory and too does not behave properly.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks it is config issue, below quick test will validate the syntax of config file

```
httpd -t  

or

apachectl -t
```

If above command returns ***syntax OK*** hope above described issue is with  directory listing, in that case create a .htaccess file and add below

```
Options -Indexes
```

or
in httpd config remove the **Indexes** flag in the below section

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        ...
</Directory>
```

If still you are facing an issue then get sample [httpd.conf](http://www.uow.edu.au/~nabg/WebServer/Chapter3/WindowsConf.html) from google for your environment and do the required changes :)

And finally it is good habit to make a backup copy of config files before we are going to edit. :)

Comment: thanks for your efforts kakurala . I got the problem. someone has set DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www//project_name"
<Directory "D:/wamp/www/project_name"> in my httpd.conf file.